# FirebaseAuth not calling startActivityForResult

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-authentication

I am implementing normal sign-in flow in FirebaseUIAuth However, **startActivityForResult** is never fired, hence The Fragments where *FirebaseAuth.getInstance()* is required crashes.
I have logged *onActivityResult*, the log never appears which confirms my case.

Here is the minified code of functions involved.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            signInFlow();
        }

        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                MyUtilsApp.showLog("authStateCalled");
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {

                } else {
                    signInFlow();
                }
            }
        };

    }

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

 protected void signInFlow() {
        MyUtilsApp.showLog("signINFlowCalled");
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

        Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build();

        MyUtilsApp.showLog(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()).toString());

        startActivityForResult(intent,RC_SIGN_IN);

    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        MyUtilsApp.showLog("onActivityResultCalled");
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Successfully signed in
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                MyUtilsApp.showLog(user.getDisplayName());
                //finish();
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to log code flow which is as follows

```
2021-01-16 15:50:28.093 29955-29955/com.example.increaseyouriq E/TAG: showLog: inOnCreate
2021-01-16 15:50:28.096 29955-29955/com.example.increaseyouriq E/TAG: showLog: signINFlowCalled
2021-01-16 15:50:28.111 29955-29955/com.example.increaseyouriq E/TAG: showLog: ComponentInfo{com.example.increaseyouriq/com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity}
2021-01-16 15:50:28.158 29955-29955/com.example.increaseyouriq E/TAG: showLog: inAttach
2021-01-16 15:50:28.159 29955-29955/com.example.increaseyouriq E/TAG: showLog: fragOnCreate
2021-01-16 15:50:28.159 29955-29955/com.example.increaseyouriq E/TAG: showLog: fragcreateview
2021-01-16 15:50:28.267 29955-29955/com.example.increaseyouriq E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.increaseyouriq, PID: 29955
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.increaseyouriq.ui.helpers.MyUtilsApp.queryProgress(MyUtilsApp.java:157)
        at com.example.increaseyouriq.ui.fragments.HomeCoursesFragment.onViewCreated(HomeCoursesFragment.java:60)
```

My homeCourse fragment calls

```
MyUtilsApp.queryRightAnswers(null);
```

Now this static method has a  line

```
DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
```

Well the pathString error in HomeCoursesFragment is due to null returned by FirebaseAuth.getInstance(), since MainActivity Failed to initialize it.

Comment: where are you using `child()`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have added additional info

Comment: it should be `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`, tell me if this works

Comment: @PeterHaddad Well now the error is "attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference"

Comment: is `signINFlowCalled` appearing in the log? If not then that's the problem, the user is not getting logged in

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes it is call, startActivityForResult never fires up. I don't know why. Can you guess it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227404/discussion-between-amansharma-and-peter-haddad).